# My Music Folder Appearing On Desktop

Tags: windows-7, desktop, music, shortcuts

I use Windows 7 and have recently been encountering a problem with the My Music folder. I keep all my music on an external hard drive and use a third party program such as VLC to play albums. I also have a large list of single MP3s that I play in WinAmp. Neither of these cause any problem but whenever I play a song in the bundled Windows Media Player a new My Music shortcut appears on the desktop.

WMP is my default player, I've tried changing it to other players but whenever I use WMP it still creates this shortcut.

The My Music folder is empty as all music is stored on the external hard drive and I've set WMP to collate, store and retain no information about anything, so I don't think it's anything to do with playlist history or anything.

Any ideas what might be happening? Any help in solving this annoyance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First step would probably be to go to the control panel and go to Default Programs. 
See if you can uncheck all of Windows Media Player's file types. That may fix the issue of WMP opening altogether. 
PS: when I boot into my Win7 partition, I'll get more info on the WMP settings and see what I can advise you.